# What makes the people in the bar laugh at the beginning of Desperado?

Tags: dialogue, translation, desperado

At the beginning of the classic Robert Rodriguez film ***[Desperado](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112851/)*** (1995), *Buscemi* (played by... [Steve Buscemi](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000114/?ref_=tt_cl_t5)) tells a tall tale about the mysterious main character of the film.

During his story, his listeners make asides in Spanish, first, Tavo (Tito Larriva), then the Bartender (Cheech Marin). After the first aside, the other listeners burst out laughing.

*First aside (after Buscemi says "It was as if the lights dimmed... just for him"):*

[image]

*Second aside (after Buscemi says "And he sat that thing beside him as if it were his girl"):*

[image]

I don't speak Spanish, so I have never been able to elucidate what they say.

***What are the asides that Tavo and the Bartender make during Buscemi's story?***

Answer (score 5):

I just rewatched [the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1PQ_d69a8c). The bartender says:

> Huevon!

Which according to [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=huev%C3%B3n) means extremely lazy or stupid person in Mexican Spanish. He could be calling the character in the story stupid for treating the guitar case like a girl.

Answer (score 3):

The first aside goes thusly

> Buscemi: It was as if the lights dimmed... just for him.
>
> Tavo: *Esto huele cargado* (Literally: This smells loaded)

A better translation is *This smells like bullshit.*

I believe @Luciano correctly answered the second part.